# how to add childItem to another childItem in a menuItem ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i need help whit this code, i have the next menuItem in ASP.NET:

1 
  -> 1.1

and i need to add to menu 1.1 a new child (1.1.1)

1 
-> 1.1 
-----> 1.1.1

but not know how to do it, this is my code:

```
    Dim menu = New MenuItem()
    menu .Text = "1"
    menu .NavigateUrl = ""
    menu1.Items.Add(menu)

    Dim menuChild = New MenuItem()
    menuChild .Text = "1.1"
    menuChild .NavigateUrl = ""
    menu.ChildItems.Add(menuChild)
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this works...

```
 Dim subMenuChild = New MenuItem()
 subMenuChild.Text = "1.1.1"
 subMenuChild.NavigateUrl = ""
 menuChild.ChildItems.Add(subMenuChild)
```

or is it something else that you are looking for?